# Specify HTML elements from *.html file and insert value to there

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a task like this, I need to create a winform with flow like this:

a textbox for user input a string value. Then, I choose an available file html, and I want to specify `<H1>` tag and insert these string to it, for example.

I found something on the internet like `HtmlTextWriter` class but it does not seem feasible...

Maybe I have not understood yet about `HtmlTextWriter`. 
Could you tell me how to use this...Special Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will have to expand on what "like this" and "like that" means.

Comment: Maybe search google for ["HtmlTextWriter example"](https://www.google.com/search?q=HtmlTextWriter+example)

Comment: You can create an xml object and treat it like a XML

Comment: You have certain Html file and you have to insert the string value in that Html file with in <H1> tag. That's what you are trying to do right.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Thanks for your help, but I haven't solved this problem yet although I tried with your recommend...

Comment: @HanjunChen are you mentioning about `XMLReader`?

Comment: @littleAnt `XElement` you have to right click reference-> Add Reference and add System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq DLLs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: insert a string value into `<H1>` tag or replace the available string value in `<H1>` that is my problem. But the first thing, I need to get over insert a string value with `HTML` file which has only one `<H1>' tag. @SH7

Comment: @littleAnt Then you will need to show the code that you used and explain how it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XElement` to rebuild the HTML document

```
    string html = @"<html>
        <body><div></div></body>
    </html>";

    string userIput = "hello world";

    var document = XElement.Parse(html);
    var newDoc = new XElement(document.Name,
        new XElement("body",
            new XElement("div",
                new XElement("h1") { Value = userIput })));
```